# combobox select item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have my `combobox` is filling from `dgv` on form load everything is ok, but i want to focus that value which i will provied.

For example:

> If my combobox contains 2 , 3 , 4, 5
>   when form load and combo box filling is end i want to first value was 4.

How i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property is probably better as it selected based on the value of the combo. SelectedIndex selects based on the Ordinal position instead of the actual value.

Comment: I agree with this, it's far more predictable.

Comment: `Items.Add` returns the index anyway, and "predictable" is that last term I would use to describe `SelectedValue`.  Easier to use, yes, but there are a number of questions with non-obvious answers... how does it match an item, does it use reference equality, value equality, `DefaultEqualityComparer`, etc?  What happens if more than one item matches?  The documentation isn't even clear that it selects an new item, as opposed to modifying the `ValueMember` of the currently selected item.

Comment: But you need to extra work to figure out the ordinal of the value you want to select, particularly if you are binding a list to the control (instead of using Items.Add). As for your concerns, equality is handled in a standard, consistent way (.Equals()), the first matching item is chosen, and yes it does select the new item. Just because the documentation is a bit vague doesn't mean not to use a particular method.